# Show that $C_1(1+||x||^2)^k \leq \sum_{|\alpha| \leq k} x^{2\alpha} \leq C_2 (1+||x||^2)^k$

Tags: combinatorics, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, normed-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that there exist constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ so that

$$C_1(1+||x||^2)^k \leq \sum_{|\alpha| \leq k} x^{2\alpha} \leq C_2 (1+||x||^2)^k,$$

for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Remember that $x^{\alpha}=x_1^{\alpha_1}x_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots x_n^{\alpha_n}$. I am trying to use the inequality
$$2|ab|\leq a^2+b^2$$.
But the question sugest use some teory of tempered distribution.

Comment: If $\ |\alpha|=\sum |\alpha_j|\ $ then $| C_1=C_2=1\ $ would do. If it is the $\max$ then it's as in the topic of normed spaces.

Comment: yes its sum norm. But I cant see the inequality.

Comment: I seem to see better than "an inequality". Indeed, I feel that there is the equality: $ (1+||x||^2)^k\ =\ \sum_{|\alpha|\le k}\,x^{2\cdot\alpha}.$ (Am  I wrong?)

Comment: @WlodAA the RHS is a sum of monic polynomials, while the LHS, for $k>1$ has binomial coefficients appearing.

Comment: @CalvinKhor, thank you, indeed, somehow I missed that, so-to-speak, the variable, after computing the power, occur in all possible orders on the left of my false equality (then they can be combined producing the binomial coefficients), while on the right, they appear in the order of increasing indices.

Comment: What is the interpretation in case $x = 0$?

Comment: @VictorHugo What do you mean? at $x=0$ it says $C_1 \le 1 \le C_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guess in the comments ( $(1+\|x\|^2)^k = \sum_{|\alpha|\le k} x^{2\alpha}$) is not correct; since none of the indices repeat, all coefficients on the right are +1, while the left hand side has positive coefficients, at least as large as binomial coefficients. Alternatively, verify that the identity is wrong if $x=(1,0,\dots,0)$: the right hand side is $k+1$ while the left hand side is $2^k$.

For the upper bound,
$$\sum_{|\alpha|\le k} x^{2\alpha} \le \sum_{j=0}^k \|x\|^{2j} \sum_{|\alpha|=j}1 \le C \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}(\|x\|^2)^j = C (1+\|x\|^2)^k. $$
Here, $C = \sup_{j=0}^k\sum_{|\alpha|=j}1$ is a constant depending on the known quantities $k,n$.

For the lower bound, if $j\neq 0$, then
$$ \sum_{|\alpha|=j} x^{2\alpha}  = \|x\|^{2j} 
\sum_{|\alpha| = j}  
\frac{x^{2\alpha}}{\|x\|^{2j}} \ge \|x\|^{2j} \frac{\sum_{m=1}^n x_m^{2j}}{\|x\|^{2j}} \ge c\|x\|^{2j}$$
where $c = \inf_{x\in\mathbb R^n} f(x)$ where $f(x) := \frac{\sum_{m=1}^n x_m^{2j}}{\|x\|^{2j}} \ge 0$. 
Note that $c=d(j)^{2j}>0$ by the equivalence of the $\ell^2$ and $\ell^{2j}$ norms on $\mathbb R^n$. ($d(j)$ depends on $n$ and $j$.) A similar bound obviously holds for $j=0$. Now
$$\sum_{|\alpha|\le k} x^{2\alpha} \ge \frac{\inf_{j'=0}^k d(j')^{2j'}}{\max_{j''=0}^k \binom{k }{j''}}\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k }{j}(\|x\|^2)^j = \tilde c (1+\|x\|^2)^k.   $$

PS this question doesn't have anything to do with the `fractional-sobolev-spaces` tag. (and your other questions too)